# No se como armar el siguiente trigger [SQL]

Tags: sql, trigger

> Tengo tres tablas:

**VIANDAS**

- ID
- NOMBRE
- ID_CLIENTE
- COSTO
- TIPO

**INGREDIENTES**

- ID
- NOMBRE
- ID_UNIDAD
- PRECIO

**VIANDA-INGREDIENTES**

- ID_VIANDA
- ID_INGREDIENTE
- CANTIDAD

Lo que quiero hacer con el trigger es, luego de actualizar el precio de un `Ingrediente`, actualizar el campo `COSTO` de cada `VIANDA` que contenga al ingrediente modificado.

El costo de la vianda se compone de **la suma total de los ingredientes, multiplicado cada uno por su respectiva cantidad** - `sumatoria(ingrediente*cantidad)`

Entonces tengo que hacer un trigger:

```
create trigger TR_actualizar_costo_vianda
on ingredientes
after update
as ``hasta aca llego``
```

> Llegue a saber que lo que tenia que hacer era un `trigger` gracias a las respuestas de usuarios de este sitio, pero la verdad que no soy para nada bueno armando sentencias sql y esta es todo un desafio, no se ni por donde podria empezarla. Agradeceré cualquier orientacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo intentaría con una cosa así. Se crea en el FROM del UPDATE la tabla con el calculo. El precio del ingrediente se obtiene filtrando el WHERE con el ID del ingrediente modificado (Tabla INSERTED). Se saca el campo ID_VIANDA para poder hacer el UPDATE solo DE aquellas viandas que tengan ese ingrediente modificado.

```
  create trigger TR_actualizar_costo_vianda
    on ingredientes
    after update
    as 

      UPDATE VIANDAS SET COSTO= t.COSTO
      FROM ( 
             SELECT vi.ID_VIANDA AS ID_VIANDA,
             SUM(precio*cantidad) AS COSTO
             FROM INGREDIENTES as i
             INNER JOIN VIANDA-INGREDIENTES as vi ON vi.ID_INGREDIENTE=i.ID
             WHERE i.id=(SELECT ins.ID FROM INSERTED ins)
             GROUP BY ID_VIANDA
       ) AS t
      WHERE ID = t.ID_VIANDA
```

Espero que te valga

Comment: No, me tira un error en ``SUM(precio*cantidad)`` y tiene sentido, ya que estos dos valores pertenecen a tablas distintas. Cantidad esta en la tabla ``menuingre`` (cuando hice esta pregunta la llame VIANDA-INGREDIENTES) y precio es de la tabla ``ingredientes``, ademas ``costo`` pertenece a la tabla ``viandas``

Comment: Pon los alias de las tablas por delante de las columnas. Es decir. VI.CANTIDAD e I.PRECIO respectivamente. El campo de COSTO del FROM es un alias, puedes cambiarlo por otra cosa pero deberas cambiarlo tambien en el SET del UPDATE.

Comment: `` MySQL ha dicho: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'FROM ( SELECT vi.id_vianda AS ID_VIANDA, SUM(i.prec' en la linea ``

Comment: No se que puede ser. Comprueba los espacios. Tampoco puedo probar ya que deberia tener tu base de datos. Solo te he puesto la SQL a ciegas. El error que te da es de sintaxis.

Comment: Mas alla de que el trigger no funciona, la consulta no esta mal (lo que esta como ``t``), el tema es que ese select me devuelve una lista de las viandas con el costo que ese ingrediente ``i.id`` representa en cada una. El tema es que yo tengo que actualizar la vianda teniendo en cuenta tambien los precios de los demas ingredientes. EJEMPLO: Si la vianda costaba 200 pesos,  y 20 pesos representaba el ingrediente actualizado que ahora vale el doble, la vianda tiene que pasar a valer 220 pesos, y esa consulta que me pasaste devolveria "40", yo esperaba que devuelva 220

Comment: Es que la problematica que has puesto arriba, pones que hay que hacer un sumatorio de (precio * cantidad), cosa que mi SQL si lo hace.

Comment: Termine en el foro en ingles, donde me explicaron que lo que estoy haciendo esta mal, debido a que un valor calculado no debe guardarse en la base, sino solamente calcularse cuando hace falta. Asi que cree otra pregunta y cambie el enfoque, en lugar del trigger lo que necesito es una consulta que devuelva el precio actual de la vianda, lo que haria que no fuera necesario andar actualizando, ya que se calcula con los precios actuales. Asi que te agradezco, pero no hice uso de tu respuesta, por lo que no puedo marcarla con el tilde verde. Igual le doy flechita arriba